# How to inject bootstrap´s tabs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to inject this example https://gist.github.com/mnewt/4228037 to my DOM after a certain event occurs. It works if I stick to "regular" HTML, but doesn't work if I try to do something like this:

```
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');

var information= '<div class="container">'+
'<div id="content">'+
    '<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">'+
        '<li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>'+
    '</ul>'+
    '<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">'+
        '<div class="tab-pane active" id="red">'+
            '<h1>Red</h1>'+
            '<p>red red red red red red</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="tab-pane" id="orange">'+
            '<h1>Orange</h1>'+
            '<p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">'+
            '<h1>Yellow</h1>'+
            '<p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="tab-pane" id="green">'+
            '<h1>Green</h1>'+
            '<p>green green green green green</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="tab-pane" id="blue">'+
            '<h1>Blue</h1>'+
            '<p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';
content.innerHTML= information;
```

Note: The IDs are there just for some styling purposes in a near future.

Also, the URL changes from www.abc.com to www.abc.com/#orange.

Comment: what's wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/L2L9kL8o/

Comment: @code-jaff ok now thats weird. In my app I only call content.innerHTML= information after the user does something. I´m starting to think I must of goofed up somewhere between information (the variable) and the innerHTML part.

Comment: Keep in mind that `twitter-bootstrap` requires jQuery, and I notice you only use Javascript here. You might have it included, but I figured I'd add this note just in case.

Answer (score -1):

If you are adding HTML AFTER the DOM has been rendered the page doesn't know those new elements are there. You need to rebind event's to their ID's or specifically bind them in the first place by ID, class, etc.

```
$('body').on('click', '#red', function(){
    doSomething();  
});
```

Comment: Be mindful of adding a jQuery answer to a question without the jQuery tag, especially if there isn't any jQuery in their question.

Comment: Bootstrap runs off jQuery. jQuery MUST exist.

Comment: But his function isn't *using* jQuery. It's using javascript, and there is no jQuery tag. I'm not saying your answer is incorrect, just that it makes the assumption that the OP wants a jQuery answer, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: There's so much special in your statement... jQuery IS Javascript.

Comment: `$('body').on()` is a jQuery function that wouldn't run without jQuery included. If I asked for a javascript answer and you posted what you did above, I would downvote it.

Comment: It doesn't ask for a javascript only answer. The user has jQuery included in his page, jQuery is the BEST and easiest answer. Get over it.

Comment: I made a simple point to be mindful of the tags and the content of the post. There's no mention of **jQuery**. We both know it's there, but you should avoid posting jQuery functions as an answer to a question that isn't tagged with jQuery. I don't know why you decided to argue that so much.

Comment: This is a bootstrap question. The bootstrap framework examples are manipulated by jQuery. They instruct you to use jQuery.  The plugin in question that is not working is written in jQuery. I'm not sure how much harder it is to explain this?

Comment: The asker's code is all in javascript, not jQuery. I know that jQuery is included; **that was never my point to begin with.** All I said was be mindful of answering ***javascript*** questions with ***jQeury***. Also editing the question to include the tag is not a solution to this discussion. Lastly, read the `reject` reason for tags: *"Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains."*